# Identifying and adapting unix-"isms" to the Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, shell, unix, export, pyramid

In the Python Pyramid [tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/humans/setup.html), I encountered this phrase:

"Windows users will need to adapt the Unix-isms below to match their environment."

It appears to relate to the "Export" command, but I am not entirely sure. The question therefore, is how do others go about this process of identifying and adapting "Unix-isms"? My only method so far is to see what isn't recognized, and obviously that could be due to different reasons.

Regarding research, I may have found a paywalled explanation for export specifically, but I'm sure there are better resources for adapting these commands.

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't that mostly refer to the use of `/` and the shell-specific commands such as `mkdir` instead of `md` and `which` ... etc?

Comment: I'll likely add a question regarding my specific brand of confusion with the Pyramid tutorial. Here though I thought it would be better for the community to ask a slightly higher level question first, and attempt to solve this problem myself. Just trying to do well as a new member of the community.

Comment: No idea what's that about with no supporting links whatsoever.  I suppose you learn Unix-isms by using scissors and cut the mouse umbilical cord.

Comment: Note that that tutorial is not an "official" tutorial shipped as part of the Pyramid docs.  The official ones treat Windows and UNIX equally.  They are at http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/#tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `$` symbol is a [**Unix prompt**](https://superuser.com/questions/57575)
- The `;` is a command separator
- `export` [**sets**](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html) sets an environment variable, similar to [**setx**](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)
- `PATH=/path/to/tutorial_workspace/venv/bin:$PATH` is modifying the `PATH` environment variable, similar to `PATH=/path/to/tutorial_workspace/venv/bin;%PATH%`
- `which` [**searches**](http://ss64.com/bash/which.html) the `PATH` for a program and returns its location.